# How to get list of files when directory listing is disabled?

Tags: html, automation, wget

I am not able to put proper title for this question, but i will try to explain it here.

If I know that there are many files in this directory:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/e/
```

like

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/e/320
https://mail.google.com/mail/e/ezweb_ne_jp.059
...
```

and many more.
But I can not list them, since directory listing might be denied as in above case.
Is there any way to list all such files. Or any workaround?

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter thanks a lot :-)

Comment: If the files are forbidden by the server owner, you shouldn't be doing otherwise you'll be banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. As far as I know you cannot get the list of all files or directories without the directory listing enabled. This cannot be done directly or there is no easy way to do this.

If you really want to find out the list of files, you will have to crawl the site and find all the links that are pointed to that directory. However, this method is not guaranteed to give you list of all files and directories as there may be many files which are not linked from anywhere and are just present there, some files which might be accessed in only some specific cases, etc. Also, if the sites see lot of traffic from your user or IP they might just ban your from the website.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can't.

At best you could spider the entire web and look for urls that refer to this directory, but unless you can look into the directory in browse mode, it is impossible to get a listing of what's in there.

In real world terms, I've got a cardboard box here, and I'll tell you there's one jelly bean in there. Tell me what else is in there. Think this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

If directory listing is disabled by server, then you can not have list of files.
You can try to do such kind of brute force, generate all possibilities of filenames.
When you receive HTTP 200, filename is valid.

But don't try to do this on public web sites, you can be blacklisted or something like this.